# How to create a list of igraph objetcs

Tags: list, loops, igraph

I have a number of igraph objetcs and I want to create a list of them to use it in a loop. I understand that the lists I tried to generate are list of names of the objetcs so my loop does not work. How can I create a igraph objetcs list?

Comment: Is this in R? Or Python?

Comment: Please provide a minimum working example.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way to do this is probably to split net into a list with one element for each unique value of community and then apply your graph building code to each piece, storing the results for each piece in another list. There are several ways to doing this type of thing in R, one of which is to use 
"lapply"

```
#Break net into pieces based on unique values of community
netSplit <- split(net,net$community)

#Define a function to apply to each element of netSplit
myFun <- function(dataPiece){
    netEdges <- NULL

    for (idi in c("nom1", "nom2", "nom3")) {
        netEdge <- dataPiece[c("id", idi)]
        names(netEdge) <- c("id", "friendID")
        netEdge$weight <- 1
        netEdges <- rbind(netEdges, netEdge)
    }

    g <- graph.data.frame(netEdges, directed=TRUE)
    #This will return the graph itself; you could change the function
    # to return other values calculated on the graph
    g
}
```

## Apply your function to each subset (piece) of your data:

result <- lapply(netSplit,FUN = myFun)